# Implementing HoloEverywhere error No resource identifier found

Tags: android, android-holo-everywhere

The following error occurs when I build my project:

```
 [2013-04-03 03:52:49 - mydemoapp] D:\My Projects\HoloEverywhere
 Library\res\layout\time_picker_holo.xml:17: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 
'importantForAccessibility' in package 'android'
```

It's been 2 days that i'm trying to implement HoloEverywhere and I'm failing. Please any expert can help?

What I did is the following:

1)I imported **HoloEverywhere Library** to eclipse

2)I imported also the contrib/**ActionBarSherlock** to eclipse as well

3)I imported also the ActionBarSherlock Library Called **library** created by Jake Wharton (Thank you Jake!)

After all those imports:

4) I right clicked on HoloEverywhere Library>Properties>Android and added the imported contrib/ActionBarSherlock which came with the HoloEverywhere zipped file. Then, I went to Java Build Path>Add>ActionBarSherlock ( The same one imported)

5)I right clicked on ActionBarSherlock>Properties>Add (added **library** the official one) and went to Android>checked(IsLibrary)

6)I right clicked on library>Properties>Android and checked **IsLibrary**

7)I also imported **android-support-v4-r12.jar** to HoloEverywhere ( I tried creating /libs folder and put it inside and I also tried the right click Properties>Java Build Path>Libraries>Add Jars

Now after creating my project called mydemoapp, I see that error:

```
  [2013-04-03 03:52:49 - mydemoapp] D:\My Projects\HoloEverywhere
 Library\res\layout\time_picker_holo.xml:17: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 
'importantForAccessibility' in package 'android'
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ok guys listen for those who are facing the same problem...

First of all get rid of **library**. Make **ActionBarSherlock** referenced by **HoloEverywhere Library** from Android (Properties ) and also imported from Java Build Path ( Properties ) .

Then right click on your project Properties>Android>Add Holoeverywhere Library. DO NOT IMPORT IT ( DO NOT GO TO JAVA BUILD PATH and ADD it )

In my case R.java was not being able to get generated so go to your manifest file , change anything and SAVE then restore it back to the default state and Save again!

A R.java will get generated and it will work like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. The fix was to check your target android version of both holoeverywhere and your project, make sure those 2 match.